# How to set onDismissListener of DialogFragment in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I write class `MyWindow` which extends `DialogFragment`

```java
public class MyWindow extends DialogFragment {
    public Button yes;
    public Button cancel;
    public Button no;
    public int result;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.save_layout, container);

        initButton(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initButton(View view) {
        yes = view.findViewById(R.id.yes_button);
        cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        no = view.findViewById(R.id.no_button);

        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                result = 1;
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                result = 0;
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                result = -1;
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to create an instance of `MyWindow` (`mywindow`) in `MainActivity`, and to execute a function of MainActivity to read `myWindow.result` after it dismisses. I tried call `mywindow.setOnDismissListener` in `MainActivity` directly but the program can't be complied. And I tried to add

```java
@Override
public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
        ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) activity).onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}
```

to MyWindow, which still doesn't work.

Is there a way to set onDismissListener of DialogInterface in MainActivity?

edit:

In `MainActivity`, I create `myWindow` with

```java
myWindow = new MyWindow();
myWindow.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "confirm_dialog");
```

Comment: How you are calling dialogfragment from mainactivity?Please post the activity code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Activity implement OnDismissListener

```
public final class YourActivity extends Activity implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        //Fragment dialog had been dismissed
    }
}
```

DialogFragment already implements OnDismissListener, just override the method and call the Activity.

```
public final class DialogFragmentCustom extends DialogFragment {

    ///blah blah

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
            ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) activity).onDismiss(dialog);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this out.